# R: visualizing p-values in a grid?

Tags: r, dataframe

So I'm reading two .csv files into dataframes containing gene expression values by brain region. They both look a bit like this:

```
   reg1   reg2     reg3   reg4   reg5    reg6    reg6    reg7     reg8
1  0.2036 0.6400  -2.2647 0.5345 0.9812 -0.0390 -1.4486 -0.1340  -1.9157
2 -0.0308 0.2991  -1.8990 0.7063 0.8807 -0.0568 -1.5150 -0.8000  -1.5115
3 -0.0242 0.6358  -2.1675 0.8432 0.8149 -0.0955 -1.3789 -0.2266  -1.5513
4 -0.8990 0.5613  -2.0289 0.8544 1.1060 -0.3846 -1.4800 -0.0717  -1.4325
5 -0.6438 0.8719  -2.2708 0.6790 1.0250 -0.3035 -1.1125 -0.3746  -1.5219
6 -0.7945 0.5943  -1.8478 0.5457 0.7989 -0.1093 -2.3242  0.2995  -1.8066
```

I'm comparing expression rate by p-value using the following to run t-tests of the genes against each other for each region (the regions are the same in both .csv files).

```
geneA = read.csv("geneA.csv")
geneB = read.csv("geneB.csv")
test.result = mapply(t.test, geneA, geneB)

#store p-values in a column with regions in a separate column:
p.values = stack(mapply(function(x, y) t.test(x,y)$p.value, geneA, geneB))

#order p-values
ordered = p.values[with(p.values, order(values)),]
```

Now what I'd like to do with these p-values is show them in a map that would look something like this (p-values are made up):

```
                  geneB

                 reg1 reg2 reg3 reg4 ...
     reg1        .02  .02  .01  .12
     reg2        .03  .03  .05  .02
```

geneA    reg3        .01  .05  .05  .05
         reg4        .01  .06  .21  .02
         ...
and so on and so forth.  Any suggestions? Something graphical is preferred.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
m1 <- as.matrix(read.table(text="   reg1   reg2     reg3   reg4   reg5    reg6    reg6    reg7     reg8
1  0.2036 0.6400  -2.2647 0.5345 0.9812 -0.0390 -1.4486 -0.1340  -1.9157
2 -0.0308 0.2991  -1.8990 0.7063 0.8807 -0.0568 -1.5150 -0.8000  -1.5115
3 -0.0242 0.6358  -2.1675 0.8432 0.8149 -0.0955 -1.3789 -0.2266  -1.5513
4 -0.8990 0.5613  -2.0289 0.8544 1.1060 -0.3846 -1.4800 -0.0717  -1.4325
5 -0.6438 0.8719  -2.2708 0.6790 1.0250 -0.3035 -1.1125 -0.3746  -1.5219
6 -0.7945 0.5943  -1.8478 0.5457 0.7989 -0.1093 -2.3242  0.2995  -1.8066",header=TRUE))

m2 <- matrix(rnorm(54),nrow=6)

fun <- Vectorize(function(i,j) t.test(m1[,i],m2[,j])$p.value)
res <- outer(1:9,1:9,FUN = "fun")

image(1:9,1:9,res,axes=FALSE,xlab="m1",ylab="m2")
axis(1, at = 1:9,labels=colnames(m1))
axis(2, at = 1:9,labels=colnames(m1))
```

[image]

---

## Edit

Here is a plot using ggplot2:

```
colnames(res) <- colnames(m1)
res <-as.data.frame(res)
res$group <- colnames(m1)

library(reshape2)
res <- melt(res,id="group")

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(res, aes(x=group, y=variable)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour =   "yellow") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red", name="p-value") +
  geom_text(aes(label=format(value,digits=2))) +
  labs(x="m1",y="m2")

print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Very much what I'm looking for, yes (and thanks!), except with explicit p-values listed numerically (as opposed to in a heatmap). 

In fact, numbers ON TOP OF a heatmap would be ideal, but I don't want to push my luck.

Comment: I added the plot you wished for.